# how to make an image logo responsive in the header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can i make the logo responsive when i resize the window
or browse the website in any device

i tried with make the width 100% or adding the class img-responsive
but it didn't worked

check this picture to understand the problem
[image]

I'm using bootstrap by the way
i just want the logo to be resonsive in any device and any size
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm at work and am not able to write sample code right now, but one way to approach this problem is to use CSS to load the images and media queries to select a specific image based on max-width. Something like `@media screen and (max-width:770px)`.

Comment: Amazing, i got the point
I just want to know the main sizes
for example
1024 / 770 / 560 / 220 px
and i'll do the rest by my self
Thanks

Comment: you could've also used the grid-system of bootstrap itself. so it sizes for example only to 4 columns if you use it with img-responsive.

Comment: @SystemDZ, happy that I got the point across. As to sizes, the answer depends on your design, of course and if you are using `less` or not. If you are using `less`, Bootstrap has group of variables which define breakpoints - for each break point, you can load a different image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem and this is what I did.

```
  <header id="parent">
    <img id="selector" class="img-responsive" src="yourdir/here.png">
  </header>
```

If you want to 'absolute' position the image you can add a relative position to the parent of your element and then add an absolute position to your child which is an image in this case.

```
 #parent{ //example .header in your case
position : relative;
 }

 #selector{
 padding-top : 2px;//to prevent image from touching top[optional]
 width : 19% !important;
 }
```

Am sure this will work because it worked for me. Please tell me once you have tried.

some of these styles are problematic when overriding, even after using '!important', so I override forcefully with javascript or jquery. But when you use javascript/jquery they obey. eg

```
  $('#selector').css({
   'padding-top' : '2px',
   'width' : '19%' //select your prefered width here.
  });
```

This is after putting the parent in a relative position. ie..

```
  $('#parent').css('position','relative')
```

Comment: I think the question the OP is raising has to do with size of image and not the position.

Comment: @SystemDZ, You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot
yes i will, i'm going to check it first